# What is "time in system" for a given job and how to retrieve?

Tags: qiskit, ibm-q-experience

I noticed that there is "time in system" for each job.

For example:

[image]

I was wondering what does this mean? I am guessing this means the time of the first shot starts on the quantum devices till the last shot ends?

Also, is there any way to retrieve it?

I checked the documentation of [IBMQJob](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.providers.ibmq.job.IBMQJob.html#qiskit.providers.ibmq.job.IBMQJob), but the only thing that is related to time is the [method time_per_step()](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.providers.ibmq.job.IBMQJob.time_per_step.html#qiskit.providers.ibmq.job.IBMQJob.time_per_step), but it only has running time, which is 15.1s in the figure.

Comment: welcome, accept answer will help a lot thank you

Comment: how to accept answer: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score -1):

Time in System is the amount of time (in seconds) that the job has been in the
system, for calculation of the Shannon entropy of the distribution over
measurement outcomes, for different numbers of shots and circuits.
(for more detailed: https://www.rsc.org/suppdata/d1/cp/d1cp05255a/d1cp05255a1.pdf)

How to retrieve job, watch: https://youtu.be/09-Qsge_qqo